# Android php mysql web service with volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, web, service

I tried this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and I'm getting this problem (shown below)

I changed the ip @ in AppConfig.java to

```
public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.134.1/android_login_api/";
```

and i disabled firewall.

I tried it on both device and emulator on android studio but none of them works

```
05-05 01:10:45.668    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration D/RegisterActivity﹕ Register Response: <br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0441</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>255576</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0921</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>279336</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>19</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.1036</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>286368</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Connect->connect(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Functions.php<b>:</b>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.1048</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>287208</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
    (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Connect.php<b>:</b>18</td></tr>
    </table></font>
    <br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'hedi'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0441</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>255576</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0921</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>279336</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>19</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.1036</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>286368</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Connect->connect(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Functions.php<b>:</b>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.1048</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>287208</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
    (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php' bgcol
05-05 01:10:45.744    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-05 01:10:45.745    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-05 01:10:45.745    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
05-05 01:10:45.745    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
05-05 01:10:45.745    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration W/System.err﹕ at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:126)
05-05 01:10:45.745    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration W/System.err﹕ at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:118)
05-05 01:10:45.745    2424-2424/info.androidhive.loginandregistration W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverRes
```